# Rename the subdirectories in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory called `data`, that contains several `folders/sub-folders` like below;

```
/training/07-21-2016-ABCD-67862/1-ROI regi images-08456/1.png
/training/08-11-2017-AESD-66874/2-ROI regi images-06521/2.png
-
-
```

I want to rename the folders/sub-folders like below;

```
/training/67862/08456/1.png
/training/66874/06521/2.png
-
-
```

note that I keep only the last 5 digits in the sub-folders as shown above (no name change in the **training folder**). How do I achieve this in python?
This is what I did;

```
temp = os.walk(test_path, topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for i in dirs:
        dir = os.path.join(root,i)

        os.rename(dir, dir[-5:]) # get only the last five digits.
```

But I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: You can learn something about ``glob``.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will do the trick:

```
temp = os.walk('training', topdown=False)
    for root, dirs, files in temp:
        for name in files:
            old_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            r1 = re.search(r'(?<=\d{5}\\).*\d{5}', old_path)
            r2 = re.search(r'(?<=training\\).*\d{5}(?=\\.*\d{5})', old_path)

            os.rename(old_path, old_path.replace(r1.group(), r1.group()[-5:]).replace(r2.group(), r2.group()[-5:]))
```

Comment: Thank you @ Zaven Zareyan. It says now "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'". Could you please help me fix it? thanks

Comment: This means that your path doesn't like the stucture `"/training/07-21-2016-ABCD-67862/1-ROI regi images-08456/1.png"` what is `old_path`?

Comment: /data/Mass-Training_P_00871_LEFT_MLO_1/07-21-2016-DDSM-56733/1-ROI mask images-11516